# Grails/Spring REQUIRES_NEW rolling back outer transaction

Tags: spring, grails

`REQUIRES_NEW` is rolling back all transactions:

I have a method marked `@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)`
within a bean that also has methods marked `@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED)`. These methods never call each other. They are called from another bean individually. However when my method that has been marked with `REQUIRES_NEW` fails, it rolls back the whole transaction, including the methods that are marked `REQUIRED` (which is problematic).

My understanding is that if factored this way Spring AOP will have a chance to intercept the `REQUIRES_NEW` method and start a new logical transaction.

The general idea looks like this:

```
@Transactional
class TransactionalBean{

     @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED) 
     public void methodA(){ //do transactional work }

     @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
     public void methodB(){ //do transactional work }
}
```

And then the calling bean looks like so:

```
@Transactional
class CallingBean{
   @Autowired
   TransactionalBean

   public void doWork(){
      TransactionalBean.methodA();
      TransactionalBean.methodB(); 
   }
}
```

So if method A and B succeed, everything is fine. However when method B fails work done in method A gets rolled back. My understanding is that when `methodB()` is invoked that it 'should' get intercepted by AOP and start a new transaction and suspend the other transaction, but it's not working. How do I fix this? I'm using Grails 2.5, Hibernate, JPA

Comment: Best way to fix it is to upgrade. 2.5 is no longer being maintained.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck on 2.5 for this project. Is it a problem with the framework?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way the `CallingBean` was marked as `@Transactional`. What is happening is that the `CallingBean` is creating a transaction, let's say `t1`. The `CallingBean` is invoking the two transactional methods methodA and methodB. Since methodA requires a transaction, it will make use of the existing transaction `t1`. However, methodB will create a new transaction as the annotation requires a new one, let's say `t2`. The transactional boundary of methodA does not end when the control exits methodA, but is kept alive until methodB is completed since the transaction started at the calling bean. Now that the transaction `t2` is failing in methodB, the exception would bubble up to the calling bean and the transaction `t1` would fail.

In order to resolve this, you can do one of the following based on your needs.

Turn off the `@Transactional` annotation in the `CallingBean` class.

```
//@Transactional
class CallingBean{
...
}
```

Update the annotation to use `noRollbackFor` option

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor={WhateverException.class})
class CallingBean{
...
}
```